# Responsive Grid Layout Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, grid-layout

I have a grid layout with four grid items.  At desktop width, the grid would be like this...

```
| 20% |     |     |       |
|     |     | 20% |       |
|     | 20% |     |  40%  |
```

If the browser gets resized to ~1023px or below then I would like the layout to look like this...

```
|       |  33%   |        |
|       |        |  33%   |
|  33%  |        |        |
---------------------------
|           100%          |
```

This is all easy peasy but here is the caveat, the heights of the grid items in the first example need to be uniform, thus using display: table-cell or min-height properties; however, when we hit the breakpoint, then 100% grid item should become an auto height grid item and not retain the display: table-cell heights.

Is this even possible to attain without using any kind of javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want somethink like this?

Try in your own code with different sizes, snippet is a **'XS'** screen.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="background-color:red;">
    Div1
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="background-color:blue;">
    Div2
</div>    
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
    Div3
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="background-color:pink;">
    Div4
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite...this doesn't satisfy the caveat that i mentioned.

All divs should be the same height when at highest resolution but when down to 1023px, only the first three should be the same height and the fourth div can be auto-height.

http://codepen.io/ascendantofrain/pen/jAZrba

Comment: Well it seems more tricky than I thought... Maybe should we define [more columns layouts](http://www.wearesicc.com/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/)?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it does not exacty match what you want (`16,7`/`16,7`/`16,7`/`16,7`/`50`% instead of `20`/`20`/`20`/`40`%) in full screen, but may be easier than writting new CSS grid classes... :/

Comment: The number of columns isn't really the issue.  The issue is the dynamic heights of the columns need to be consistent regardless of their content.